# Search a string and return multiple values from another column

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

```
Return Lookup Array Lookup Value    Expected Output
A   2   1   NA
B   2   2   A, B, C
C   2   3   D,E
D   3   4   F, G
E   3   5   NA
F   4   6   NA
G   4   7   NA
```

This is what the table looks like. The fourth column is what I expect the return values. I am using the lookup value in column 3 in column 2, the output is in column 4.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need multiple values returned in the same cell you are probably going to need some VBA here:

```
Function doLookup(lookupValue As String) As String
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim searchCell As Range
    Dim searchValue As String

    'What range are we searching here?
    Set searchRange = Sheet1.Range("B1:B" & Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row())

    'Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each searchCell In searchRange

        searchValue = searchCell.Value

        'If we find a match...
        If searchValue = lookupValue Then

            'If this is not the first thing in the list, then add a comma
            If doLookup <> "" Then doLookup = doLookup & ","

            'Add the thing we found
            doLookup = doLookup & searchCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next searchCell
End Function
```

Stick this in a new module and then in D1 use the formula `=DoLookup(C1)` and it should spit out what you are looking for. If the list is very large, then don't expect this to be too snappy.

Comment: I created a new module and entered the lookup column. It is not returning anything. Thank for looking into this by the way.

Comment: What do you mean, "Entered the lookup column"?

Comment: I modified the script and used D column instead. I did doLookup(g2). I made sure the sheet name and the lookup array column matches. I get "#VALUE!"

Comment: So you are looking up into D with that `Set searchRange...` line? And the value you are looking up is in `g2`, but you are getting a #Value? That is a hard one to diagnose over the internet. The only thing that might be funky is that bit that says `doLookup = doLookup & searchCell.Offset(0, -1).Value`. That's assuming that the value you want to comma seperate into a list is in the `C` column since that's `-1` from `D`. I still can't imagine why that would through a `#VALUE` though.

Comment: Yes. So this is the only thing I edited. 
Set searchRange = SHEETNAME.Range("D1:D" & SHEETNAME.Range("D" & SHEETNAME.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row())

Comment: Is this script case sensitive?